# Show that $ Y \subseteq A^*$ is decidable

Tags: decidability

Let A be a nonempty alphabet, $X ⊆ A^*$ a decidable set, and $Y ⊆ A^*$
be a semi-decidable set. We assume that $Y ⊆ X$ and that $X \setminus  Y ⊆ A^*$ is semi-decidable. Show that then the set Y ⊆ A∗ is decidable.

I am looking for some ideas where to start this problem. I think we need 2 TM's which check each input simultaneously. But some further ideas where to start would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in A^*$ be your input string. We can check that $x \in X$ and, if that is not the case, reject immediately (since we know that $x \not\in X \supseteq Y$).

Now, we know that exists a Turing machine $T_1$ that accepts $Y$. Moreover, there exists a Turing machine $T_2$ that accepts $X \setminus Y$. Interleave the execution of $T_1(x)$ and $T_2(x)$. Eventually, one of $T_1(x)$ and $T_2(x)$ must halt and accept. If $T_1(x)$ accepts, then accept. If $T_2(x)$ accepts, then reject.

Comment: what does interleave exactly mean in your context?

Comment: Execute one step of $T_1$, then one step of $T_2$, then another step of $T_1$, then another step of $T_2$, and so on so forth.